# YA TV series: Iron Daisy, alien ship in a swamp

Tags: story-identification

It keeps bothering me a while and I'm trying to identify this young adult tv series, probably US or Australian production, that I've seen somewhere in the late 80s/early 90s

- Two kids arrive for holidays to theirs uncle (granddad?) farm. The farm lies near swamp area but locals say that the swamp is "taboo"
- On the top of the house there is a strange looking ornament, that people call "the Iron Daisy". Later kids find a painting from early XIX century,which shows, that the Daisy was already mounted in its place over an hundred years ago.
- Later kids notice that the Daisy is moving and trying to communicate with them. This leads to the discovery, that the ornament is in fact a communication equipment from an ancient alien space probe.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A New Zealand production, [Children of the Dog Star](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0271902/?ref_=nv_sr_1).

The brass daisy.
[image: The brass daisy]

The plot synopsis from wikipedia:

> On holiday at her uncle's farm in New Zealand, Gretchen befriends Ronny, a Māori boy with a troubled city past, and Bevis the birdwatching son of a loathed developer. Tension is already high as the developer wants to buy and drain a local swamp for a housing estate, but Ronny's uncle is the guardian of a traditional Māori tapu (taboo/curse) upon the swamp. The swamp must not be touched—something sleeps there that must not be awakened. Something unnatural.